# C program giving different results on OSX and windows

Tags: c, macos, compiler-construction

I wrote a recursive function in C to reverse an integer (123 -> 321) which worked fine when I ran it on my Mac, but behaves strangely when my instructor ran it on her computer running Windows.

```
int rev(int num)
{
    int base;

    if (num < 10) return (num); 

    base = pow(10,(int)log10(num));
    return(rev(num/10)+num%10*base);
}
```

For example, on OSX calling rev(8765) returns 5678, On Windows, rev(8765) returns 5672. I don't have access to a Windows machine to try to run the program in debug mode, so I've been having a hard time trying to guess what the issue is. I would greatly appreciate any insight!

Environment:

I am using using OSX 10.8 and GCC 4.2. I'm pretty sure my instructor is using MinGW as her compiler.

Comment: Which compiler was used on the Windows side?

Comment: She uses Dev C++, and I think MinGW comes with that by default.

Comment: Don't use floating point for things like this unless you're a numerical analysis expert.

Comment: if this was slashdot then the reply would be - "what do you expect from M$ windoze?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pow` and `log10` are not required to be correctly rounded; the results produced by them can and will differ between platforms, even for cases that “should be” exact like in your example.  In this case, OS X produces a more accurate result than Windows, which results in errors that show up only in the Windows output.

A *much* better solution would be to use repeated division and multiplication by 10 in integer, and not use floating-point at all (there is a very clean recursive solution similar to yours, without requiring that you compute `base`).

---

As an aside, a mini-rant:  It’s *shameful* that so many math libraries do not correctly handle small powers of ten and two in `log10`, `log2`, `exp2` and `pow`.  It is not hard to design these functions such that they do the “right thing” for these cases, and it can be done without adversely affecting performance of other cases.  While it is not required by the standard, it is a simple thing to do and it helps to save inexperienced programmers from (exceptionally common) errors like this one.

Comment: I am not sure how generally it can be said that special cases for powers of ten for `pow()` do not adversely affect the rest of the function (in aspects other than performance). Perhaps the designers of Windows' `pow()` function are very proud of having designed a function such that `pow(0xA.0000000000008p0, 2)` is larger than `pow(10, 2)`, same as with the mathematical function, and that this property would be broken if they special-cased powers of integers. It seems to me that the right way to make an unsurprising `pow()` is to make it accurate to one ulp, not to make special cases.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: that's exactly what I mean.  I'm not talking about adding special cases; I'm talking about making these functions sufficiently accurate that the cases in question fall out correctly, which isn't hard.